# Need of KDB patch for powerpc Architecture

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, powerpc, kgdb

I am using Linux Kernel Version 2.6.34.6 with powerPC. I knew that KDB was
merged with Kernel mainline 2.6.35. Hence I need to apply KDB patch with my
kernel,

But I couldn't find any patch for powerPC in the following place

ftp://oss.sgi.com/www/projects/kdb/download/

Can you help me to get patch for powerpc?

Answer (score 1):

Officially PowerPC doesn’t provide patch for KDB and it is also not listed here.

ftp://oss.sgi.com/www/projects/kdb/download/latest/README

Answer from oss.sgi.com forum

http://oss.sgi.com/archives/kdb/2003-06/msg00027.html